# Not inserting data to custom field in wp_users table

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I need custom data that's why I have created one column which name `company_name` when apply insert query then all data inserted but `company_name` data not inserting.

below my code example:

```
$userdata = array(
    'user_login'  =>  $u_email,
    'user_email'    =>  $u_email,
    'display_name'  => $u_email,
    'user_pass'   =>  $pass,
    'company_name'   =>  $cname
);

wp_insert_user( $userdata );
```

When I debugging then showing example:

```
array(5) {
 ["user_login"]=>
 string(12) "ss@gmail.com"
 ["user_email"]=>
 string(12) "ss@gmail.com"
 ["display_name"]=>
 string(12) "ss@gmail.com"
 ["user_pass"]=>
 string(6) "123456"
 ["company_name"]=> // Without this all are inserting but why
 string(2) "sa"
}
```

I'm a new for WP.

Comment: Because there's no `company_name` field in a table?

Comment: @u_mulder Yes I have `company_name` field in a table (wp_users)

Answer (score 0):

The wp_insert_user function does not work with custom fields. I assume you would have to do a SQL query to insert the values.